# I can´t understand why my mr-auto is not working (using Bootstrap)

Tags: bootstrap-4

Before "home" in this navbar, I would like to put all my content to the right. I am using mr-auto but it is not working, any suggestions?

```
<header class="header_area">
    <div class="main-menu">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"> <img src="./img/logo.png" alt="logo"> </a>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                    <div class="mr-auto"></div>
                    <ul class="navbar-nav">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
```

Comment: "Before" and "to the right" are contradictions. Reading left to right, "before" would be to the left of home, not to the right. Which do you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you want the `Home` on the left and everything else to the right.  The `mr-auto` and `ml-auto` are part of the flexbox.  So add `d-flex` to the container.

```
<header class="header_area">
  <div class="main-menu">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
        <div class="container-fluid d-flex">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"> <img src="./img/logo.png" alt="logo"> </a>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse " id="navbarNav">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="mr-auto">Right side</div>
        </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: A bit misleading since `margin: auto` isn't restricted to flexbox (see [here](https://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css-margin-auto/)), but otherwise good.

Comment: @ConnorLow Agreed. I should've mentioned my answer is specific to bootstrap. The `ml-auto` and `mr-auto` utility classes have a dependency in flexbox layout.  Here is creator of bootstrap: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/21853#issuecomment-277487682

Comment: To clarify, `mr-auto` just sets `margin-right: auto!important;`. I'm not sure what he's talking about. This doesn't restrict to `display: flex;`; it can work with most fixed-width parents.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have tried it out and it is working

Answer (score 0):

run below code on large screen. All content after home is align to right. I think you want this. If this is not your answer then please let me know in comment section

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<header class="header_area">
    <div class="main-menu">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"> Your Logo here </a>
                  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav">
                         <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                        <li class="nav-item ">
                            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
                        </li>
                         <li class="nav-item ml-lg-auto">
                            <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="#">About</a>
                        </li>
                         <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="#">Contact</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: actually thanks a lot, yeah I was trying to keep the home button on the left and everything on the right part. However it was not working